# SQL Bulk Copy Utility adding Carriage Returns to JSON files

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, bcp

We're using a SQL bcp call to write data from a stored procedure out to a JSON file.  When I run it and open up that file there are CRLF's added and it's breaking it into lines.  This causes problems with validation and if you try to format with Notepad++ or JSON Buddy it throws a parsing error.

```
set @cmd = 'bcp "exec [OurServer].[dbo].[sp_OurStoredProcedure]" queryout "'+@outputFile+'" -UTF8 -T'
exec master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

The stored procedure is using FOR JSON PATH at the end of the my SELECT statement to parse my results into JSON.

The output looks like this in Notepad++ when viewing all characters:
[image]

Comment: This is how long JSON is streamed back to the client -- as individual rows. I don't think `bcp` is intelligent enough to compensate. In particular, while you can configure the row terminator with `-r`, you cannot configure it to be entirely absent (I think, though `-r ''` is worth a shot).

Comment: There is a fix (cast to `nvarchar(max)`), if you can show your procedure code we can show you how. Pray tell *why* are you executing using `xp_cmdshell`, it's dangerous, if you need a batch then use a batch cmd, or Powershell. SQL is not a generalized scripting language

Comment: I found that CAST workaround.  And it worked and I thought I had this resolved.  However, then I ran it on our full dataset and it's cutting off the dataset.  I thought a varchar(max) could be up to 2TB and this is only about 115MB of data.  Any idea why it would cut off like that?

Comment: SELECT CAST((
SELECT 
ProductID 'ID',
ProductCost 'Cost'
FROM products
FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('feedProducts')
) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS XmlData

Comment: It cuts off after 2022540 characters

Comment: I'm surprised it outputs anything with `-UTF8` in the command line parameters.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue here. When I execute `bcp "select (select * from Database.dbo.Table for json path)" queryout D:\BigResults.json -w -C RAW -S(local) -T` it outputs a 386MiB file and the JSON has no linebreaks when viewed in Notepad, Notepad++ or VS Code. Perhaps there's something going on in your stored procedure code?

Comment: Well, I'm able to run the stored procedure form C# and load it into a StreamWriter file object.  When I do that the file has no issues.  However, once I try to call it using bcp it either adds CRLF to the lines or, if I wrap it in varchar(max) it cuts is off.  I tried the parameters above, still no luck,:  'bcp "exec [OurServer].[dbo].[sp_OurStoredProcedure]" queryout "'+@outputFile+'" -w -C RAW -T'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were finally able to get the desired output.
We had been trying to CAST the result as an nvarchar(MAX) like this:

```
SELECT CAST(
            (SELECT ProductID 'ID', ProductCost 'Cost' 
             FROM products FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('feedProducts') 
            ) 
            AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS feedData
```

After a lot of trial and error we loaded into a variable directly and then returned that variable from our stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @txtResult NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @txtResult = (
                  SELECT ProductID 'ID', ProductCost 'Cost' 
                  FROM products FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('feedProducts') 
                 )
SELECT @txtResult as feedData
```

When we call our bcp utility below the second procedure works, while the first one does not.

```
bcp "exec [DatabaseName].[dbo].[sprocName]" queryout "'+@outputFile+'" -T -w
```

The first procedure cuts off our data and does not give us a complete result while the second procedure gives us the entire return and we get the file we have been looking for.